# Why am i getting tis error message? Parsing error: '>' expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, react-context

So I'm trying to create a context and keep getting this error:

> Line 12:31:  Parsing error: '>' expected.

I can't seem to find the issue.

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';

export const UserContext = createContext({});
export const UserContextProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(1);
  const values = {
    number,
    setNumber,
  };
  return <UserContext.Provider value={values}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>;
};
```

Comment: What line in the example is "Line 12"?

Comment: the line of UserContextProvider

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxLZpSqUDCEAdpQB7wC+cAZlBCHADktdDEEBuAFCSkrSLDhpmheAFViURi1nwAvIpENmbGAAocHAJRTZ8+EqYq46pJuM6ACnwBuwACauAFyIqBgAdABi9HD65ooAFsAANn60THBWMQB8uJJwisrwANpM+CAARq7YxDAAcmWVUAC6MQTEZBRIpgCM1nkFjvDeKEn4SIStOP35pRVV03A19XNQmP0cUvm0MPhQ6QA8Lm7a7GFeEL4BUHDDo0i6OLdjhBxZOGiJKWkc+wD0R1oTGcfP5XFkpBsgA seems to think there is no error.

Comment: Are you using TypeScript? What's the file extension? ts? tsx?

Comment: evolutionxbox: Wired i'm going to restart my computer and see if that helps

Comment: JulianG: It is a tsx file

Answer (score 0):

Hi Marv,

What you are returning is not matching the expected return for a React.FC type.

Please try the following:

```
export const UserContextProvider: React.FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }): ReactElement => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(1);
  const values = {
    number,
    setNumber,
  };
  return React.createElement(UserContext.Provider, { value: values }, children);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help :D it seem to have sorted itself out when i restarted vs code